# Facebook share link with more than one image

Tags: facebook, share

I've came across this share https://www.facebook.com/lensculture/posts/10153590621527368 from LensCulture:

[image]

and I was wondering how they managed to achieve a share like that, with multiple images/thumbnails. Basically each image forwards to the same link, which is https://www.lensculture.com/articles/joanna-mrowka-streets-of-the-world-piece-by-piece

How did they create a share like that? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is achieved when webpage has OpenGraph tags with multiple images. Details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup).

If you view source of the [link](https://www.lensculture.com/articles/joanna-mrowka-streets-of-the-world-piece-by-piece), you can see 3 instances of og:image tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://photo1.lensculture.com/large/f7cae4af-f442-44fe-a162-0d2a0293dbdc.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://photo2.lensculture.com/large/b678eb67-da99-40a4-86df-6dde6d9d9aef.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://photo0.lensculture.com/large/9492a534-9ac7-423a-8ff7-776a72fbce31.jpg" />
```

So, if you would like to display multiple images in a FB post with link, you should add og:image tags to the webpage.

FB examines the link, finds images and displays them in post.

Comment: But if you paste that link in your timeline (to share) it will display only one image... I mean, you can choose between the three of them but only one will be displayed in the end.

Comment: I can see all 3 images when I paste that link, all 3 are selected and I can even change destination url for each image!

Comment: Thats weird as hell! You paste the link e.g. in your timeline right? I can't understand why I can only use one image. Can you send me a screenshot?

Comment: Aaaah I tried again in my page and it works! Looks like it only works when pasting in pages! Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to set different titles for images?

Comment: It's no longer working. Actually it's not possible to share a link with an image gallery.

Answer (score 0):

We could do it with multiple og:image tabs before, but this feature is no longer working.