# Facebook share multiple images as a gallery

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I want to achieve that my shared website post looks like this:

[image]

I tried it with multiple og:image tags, but this just resolves in the option that I can select the image that I want to get shown with my post.
Any chance to achieve that, or is this just possible when I create a image gallery directly on facebook?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook share link with more than one image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506661/facebook-share-link-with-more-than-one-image)